# What is the robust way to check form input values in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I have a form and want the form input values to be check. If the values pass the check, then values can be stored in DB. I know I can check them in view, controller, or even model. I think probably the best way is to check them in all the three parts, and only check them in view before submit could cause problem because others can manually modify and send the request to the controller.

So for example, I have user variable in view. I don't want date type attribute `user.start_date` to be modify to be earlier than `user.apply_date`, how should I make the protection robust?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for are model validations:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `date_validator` gem (https://github.com/codegram/date_validator)

It allows for validations like this:

`validates :start_date, date: { after: :apply_date }`

Answer (score -1):

Doing it in the model, as that's the usual way. Ruby on Rails supports model errors extensively, and if there's an error you can simply redisplay the record and the errors in that record.

There are standard validations you can do to ensure a value is present, is unique, etc.

You can also do custom validations in the model

```
validate :start_date_cannot_be_before_apply_date

def start_date_cannot_be_before_apply_date
  if start_date < apply_date
    errors.add(:start_date, "can't be before the apply date")
  end
end
```